# Mixing concurrency::parallel_for and async task

Tags: c++, azure, visual-c++, concurrency

Is it "ok" to create tasks with `parallel_for`?

```
concurrency::concurrent_vector<concurrency::task<void>> tasks;
concurrency::parallel_for(0, length, [tasks](int i) {
    tasks.push_back(Upload_Async(i));
});
concurrency::when_all(tasks.begin(), tasks.end()).wait();
```

Comment: I simplified the code, the parallel_for part is responsible for producing the content for the async upload part.

I wanted to know if this kind of scenario mix properly. I did some extra test and it seems to be stable.

Answer (score 0):

If `Upload_Async` is truly asynchronous, then it just starts the task and returns it, it doesn't do any of the work itself. That means that using `parallel_for` here does not make any sense, it won't speed up your code, it only adds overhead.

Comment: Yes I agree, simple loop would be ok in this case.

I oversimplified the code sample the parallel_for is responsible for producing the content for the upload.

I would like the high CPU tasks to be performed in parallel and the I/O tasks async

I have tested it with 3 nested parallel_for that produce upload tasks and it seems to work well so far